# SOAP libraries for PHP

Tags: php, soap

Is there complete list of SOAP libraries for PHP?
I am looking for complete list of available SOAP libraries to make comparison chart.
So far I've found Zend_Soap, Nusoap, native PHP SOAP support (via module). Can you suggest more?

**UPDATE:** As harke suggested I am asking everybody to help keep fresh this list of PHP SOAP libraries in this topic. If you are contributor or user of any not listed library please add your answer below.

Comment: There will never be a complete list. Also consider to make this a reference question, add your list as an answer (or add it to the wiki answer below) and ask others to participate. That would be more friendly and probably be allowed by the FAQ.

Comment: I created a Library in the past to develop web services that can Generate WSDL specification document and handle in/out SOAP messages. It also supports custom data types like array of objects etc. Look into the following URL: http://asimishaq.com/resources/easy-soap-web-service-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know of these:

- [Nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)
- [PHP SOAP Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) (based on [libxml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php))
- [WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/)
- [Zend_Soap](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html)

Comment: Zend_Soap is a wrapper for the native SoapClient and SoapServer. An updated version of the NuSoap Library for 5.3 is here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoapforphp53

Comment: It's been almost 3 years... can you guys recommend the latest working Soap libraries for PHP? SoapClient doesn't cut it sometimes- it fails to parse all XML responses and it doesn't support multi-part messages at all. I'd try to code it myself but I don't have much experience in either C or PHP internals.

Comment: *"it fails to parse all XML responses"* I don't think so that it fails to parse **all** XML responses (more likely *some*).  You can extend from **SoapClient** and intervene / inspect in case you get something wired. Don't know if it works for mult-part messages. Here is [a very simlpe example that shows extending **SoapClient**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971320/367456), just put it together yesterday.