# How to set mustUnderstand attribute soap in php?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

i've tried to set **mustUnderstand** attribute to my xml header but not able to sort it out , here is my code snippet,

```
$actionurl = array('Action'=>'www.example.com');
$headers = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Action',$actionurl,true);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
$d = $client->__soapCall('MethodName',array($params));
```

And my request xml ,which to be matched and which i want after setting up atribute ,

```
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">www.example.com</Action>
```

so i'm confused about this 'namespace' first param in soapheader method.what it it and why do we use just same? Was referring  [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php) and it didn't work at all.Can anyone help me out to get that exact xml request format?

Answer (score 3):

First of all if you want to compare what you create with your code against the XML you have as an example to target for, you need to have something to look into the XML the **SoapClient** will create.

You can achieve this by mocking the **SoapClient**:

```
/**
 * Class MockSoapClient
 */
class MockSoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $lastRequest;

    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        $config = ['input-xml' => 1, 'indent' => 1, 'wrap' => 0, 'indent-attributes' => 1];

        $this->lastRequest = tidy_repair_string($request, $config);

        return "";
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getLastRequest()
    {
        return $this->lastRequest;
    }
}
```

You can replace the normal **SoapClient** with this new **MockSoapClient** which is able to show the request which **SoapClient** would have been created.

Let's fake a request like yours:

```
$client = new MockSoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                         'uri'      => "http://test-uri/"));

$actionurl = array('Action' => 'www.example.com');

$header = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE', 'Action', $actionurl, true);

$client->__soapCall("echoVoid", array(), null, $header);
```

and see how the request would look like:

```
echo $client->getLastRequest();
```

Here the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://test-uri/"
                   xmlns:ns2="NAMESPACE"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
      <item>
        <key>Action</key>
        <value>www.example.com</value>
      </item>
    </ns2:Action>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:echoVoid />
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The interesting part here is the soap header:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns2:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
    <item>
      <key>Action</key>
      <value>www.example.com</value>
    </item>
  </ns2:Action>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Here "`ns2:`" is the prefix of the "`NAMESPACE`" namespace which is the wrong one. In your example:

```
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">www.example.com</Action>
```

The namepspace of the `<action>` element is "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none`". So "`NAMESPACE`" has to be replaced with "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none`".

The `mustUnderstand` attribute is in the correct namespace, so this is fine. That's not wondering, as it's one of the standard Soap namespaces, so those are predefined and you don't need to take much care here. Only their prefixes differ, but as long as the different prefixes refer to the same namespace, there is no difference.

The third point which is wrong is the content of the `<action>` element, you only need a string in there, not the `<item>`-`<key>`/`<value>` construct which is because of the array you have. Let's try this again:

```
$namespace = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none';
$actionurl = 'www.example.com';

$header = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'Action', $actionurl, true);
```

And now the output looks very much correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://test-uri/"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">www.example.com</ns2:Action>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:echoVoid />
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I hope this answer helps you to understand some of the basics of [XML namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) here as well as how you can more easily debug the soap-request you create here by inspecting the requests XML.