# How to dynamically create a SOAP request using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I am trying to create a SOAP request for an API like below
in some case I will need to add other tags under `<ticketId>int</ticketId>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetServiceTicket xmlns="http://connectwise.com">
          <credentials>
            <CompanyId>string</CompanyId>
            <IntegratorLoginId>string</IntegratorLoginId>
            <IntegratorPassword>string</IntegratorPassword>
          </credentials>
          <ticketId>int</ticketId>
        </GetServiceTicket>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

What is the correct way in PHP to write this code not using old and simple fashion string concatenation technique.

I thought about using SimpleXMLElement

so here is what I have done

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml/>');

$envelop = $xml->addChild('soap:Envelope');
$envelop->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$envelop->addAttribute('xmlns:xsd','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$envelop->addAttribute('xmlns:soap','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$body = $envelop->addChild('soap:Body');
$action = $body->addChild('GetServiceTicket');
$action->addAttribute('xmlns','http://connectwise.com');
$credentials = $action->addChild('credentials');

$CompacnyId = $credentials->addChild('CompacnyId','string');
$IntegratorLoginId = $credentials->addChild('IntegratorLoginId','string');
$IntegratorPassword = $credentials->addChild('IntegratorPassword','string');

$ticketId = $action->addChild('ticketId', 'int');

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

But the output show up like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <Envelope xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
            <GetServiceTicket xmlns="http://connectwise.com">
                <credentials>
                    <CompacnyId>string</CompacnyId>
                    <IntegratorLoginId>string</IntegratorLoginId>
                    <IntegratorPassword>string</IntegratorPassword>
                </credentials>
                <ticketId>int</ticketId>
            </GetServiceTicket>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
</xml>
```

How can I correct the output?

Comment: If it is a SOAP api why arent you using SOAPClient? PHP 5 and above has the SOAPClient class which helps you take care of these type of requests.

Comment: How do I do that? do you have an example?

Comment: Here you go : http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php .Generating the XML and submitting it as a HTTP request could really be painful especially when it comes to parsing the responses.

Comment: And to preview the XML send to the SOAP server, you can temporarily exchange the **SOAPClient** with a mock as I've shown in this existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971320/367456

Comment: I have another question.. do you mind looking over it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548188/how-to-use-soapclient-to-connect-to-non-wsdl-api