# PHP SOAP XML request and response

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, asmx

I am trying to generate SOAP + XML request using PHP:

Data info to post as below:

URL to send request: https://www.somedomain.com/ws/ws_CardRequest_test.asmx

```
    POST /ws/ws_CardRequest_test.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.somedomain.com
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: length
    SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetCardBalance"
```

Request as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetCardBalance xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <UserID>string</UserID>
          <PWD>string</PWD>
          <CardID>int</CardID>
        </GetCardBalance>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

How can I generate exactly same request?

My Existing Code as below:

```
    $soapUrl = "https://www.somedomain.com/ws/ws_CardRequest_test.asmx";
    $login = "user";
    $password = "pwd";

    try{

        $opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                )
            );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $client = new SoapClient($soapUrl,
                                 array('stream_context' => $context,
                                       'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

        $result = $client->checkVat(array( 'UserID'  => $login, 'PWD' => $password, 'CardID' => 18));
        pr($result);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Output of Above Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://www.somedomain.com/ws/ws_CardRequest_test.asmx">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Echo>
    <GetCardBalance><UserID>userid</UserID><PWD>pwd</PWD><CardID>18</CardID>
     </GetCardBalance></ns1:Echo>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
     </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Awaiting for exact solution to above issue.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: $soapUrl = "https://www.somedomain.com/ws/ws_CardRequest_test.asmx";
$login = "user";
$password = "pwd";
try{

    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
            )
        );

 $context = stream_context_create($opts);
 $client = new SoapClient($soapUrl,
                             array('stream_context' => $context,
                                   'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

    $result = $client->checkVat(array( 'UserID'  => $login, 'PWD' => $password));
    pr($result);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: Don't paste code in comments. Add it to your question and show which request it is creating. Your example code must not be perfect, you should just show at which specific stage you're stuck. For obtaining your **SoapClient**s request XML, see this [**MockSoapClient** example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971320/367456)  in a related question [How to set mustUnderstand attribute soap in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28967554/367456) that show how to debug your SOAP requests (your case might be different but the technique can be applied for different problems).

Comment: I have edited the question with existing code and its output - kindly suggest solution for this