# Is there any way to parse really huge SOAP response by PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I need to get and parse SOAP response, but SoapClient tells me like this:

Out of memory (allocated 387186688) (tried to allocate 87 bytes)

In other words, response is really huge so PHP (SoapClient) can't parse it. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: You can either increase the allowed memory or split the request in parts.

Comment: Check & try one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9633919/1155760

Comment: Look at XMLReader, this can give you a good balance  of being able to use SimpleXML for ease of use, but working with chunks of the file as opposed to all of the file in one go.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php has an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php. Both libs stream the xml "line by line". So you have minor memory consumption. You are able to parse parts of a xml, too.