# How to send XML to supplier as a request and receive a response using SOAP 1.2 and WSDL?

Tags: php, xml

I have a test to do by tomorrow (sorry for short notice). I can't seem to figure out how to send XML to supplier as a request and receive a response? I'm supposed to send a request in php. Send data to client back to server. I think for the client I need 2 lines of code. 1st line of code is for request 2nd line of code for response. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                 xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                 xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <soap12:Body>
        <OTA_HotelAvailRQ SummaryOnly="true">
            <POS>
                <Source ISOCountry="BRL">
                    <RequestorID ID_Context="txml" MessagePassword="txml">
                    </RequestorID>
                </Source>
            </POS>
            <AvailRequestSegments>
                <AvailRequestSegment>
                    <StayDateRange Start="2015-09-07" End="2015-09-09" />
                    <RoomStayCandidates>
                        <RoomStayCandidate>
                            <GuestCounts>
                                <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="2"/>
                                <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="8" Count="1" Age="4" />
                            </GuestCounts>
                        </RoomStayCandidate>
                    </RoomStayCandidates>
                    <HotelSearchCriteria>
                        <Criterion>
                            <Address>
                                <CityName>Berlin</CityName>
                                <StateProv StateCode="" />
                            </Address>
                            <HotelRef HotelCode="0" PropertyClassCode=""/>
                            <RoomStayCandidates>
                                <RoomStayCandidate RoomType="" RoomTypeCode="" RoomLocationCode="" 
                                                   RoomViewCode="">
                                </RoomStayCandidate>
                            </RoomStayCandidates>
                            <MealPlan Code=" "/>
                        </Criterion>
                    </HotelSearchCriteria>
                </AvailRequestSegment>
            </AvailRequestSegments>
        </OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>


 Thanks in advance! I am using SOAP 1.2 WSDL, php and XML
```

Comment: Well, you'll need a few more than 2 lines of code. Fasting would probably be to use a soap library to make your request. [There are several.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633858/soap-libraries-for-php). If you wanted to do a manual request (likely what the test is asking for), you would just need to perform a curl request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP: SoapClient class to solve your problem:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

You can find several code examples online for sending XML request and receiving XML response using PHP Soap Client class library.

Comment: I need to have an XML file on server ready for request
then use client to send request and take response

finally input form data to xml file